# [Error][DataGridView] Index out of Range

Tags: c#, datagridview

I receive an "Index out of Range" error when I try to change text on Columns Header. See code below:

```
private void cboMonth_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvAnnual.DataSource = null;
    dgvAnnual.Rows.Clear();
    dgvAnnual.Columns.Clear();

    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = ReloadData(dtTable, cboMonth.Text);
    dgvAnnual.DataSource = bSource;

    //Testing Code
    Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Columns.Count); //Col = 4
    Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Rows.Count); //Row = 10

    //The Code below is Working
    string[] str = {"Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"};
    For(int i = 0;i<dvgAnnual.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        dvgAnnual.Columns[i].HeaderText = str[i];  //<----- It's ok if it's stay in Loop For, event if I replace i by "0"
    }

    //The Code below not working if it stay outside For
    dgvAnnual.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Col1"; //<----- Error if stay alone like this
}
```

Comment: For(int i = 0;i<=dvgAnnual.Columns.count;i++) should be '<' ! and of course 'Count'..

Comment: Your code has at least 2 errors that don't compile or make it crash. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Taw My failed, I'm correct it in my code

Comment: `For` loop is case sensitive by the way its `for` also debug your code and think about it from a logical standpoint why it works inside the loop vs outside the loop.. also Column Indexes are `0` based not `1` based also `dgvAnnual.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Col " + 1;` will error out as well.. you cannot assign an integer to a Text value change your code to this for testing `dgvAnnual.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Col " + 1.ToString();`

Comment: Well. you still din't get the spelling right but the main issue is probably that you have more than 4 columns..

Comment: I doesn't understand. i't always work if stay inside the Loop.

Comment: please correct your code that you have posted.. still has syntax errors `For(   )` should be lower case `for(int i = 0; i < dvgAnnual.Columns.count;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Working Code :

```
    private void cboMonth_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dgvAnnual.DataSource = null;
       dgvAnnual.Rows.Clear();
       dgvAnnual.Columns.Clear();

       BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
       bSource.DataSource = ReloadData(dtTable, cboMonth.Text);
       dgvAnnual.DataSource = bSource;

       //Using for testing
       Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Columns.Count); //Col = 4
       Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Rows.Count); //Row = 10

       //This Code below Working
       string[] str = {"Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"};
       For(int i = 0;i<dvgAnnual.Columns.Count;i++)
       {
           dvgAnnual.Columns[i].HeaderText = str[i];  //<----- It's ok if it's stay in Loop For, event if I replace i by "0"
       }
    }
```

Not Working:

```
    private void cboMonth_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvAnnual.DataSource = null;
        dgvAnnual.Rows.Clear();
        dgvAnnual.Columns.Clear();

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = ReloadData(dtTable, cboMonth.Text);
        dgvAnnual.DataSource = bSource;

        //Testing Code
        Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Columns.Count); //Col = 4
        Console.WriteLine(dgvAnnual.Rows.Count); //Row = 10

        //This code below not working
        dgvAnnual.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Col " + 1; //<----- Error: Index out of Range
    }
```

Error catch on Watch1

```
    +   dgvAnnual.Columns[0]    'dgvAnnual.Columns[0]' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The value of the Columns is 4 here but in the loop you have ranged it i = 0; to i<=4 means total number is 5. so change your range of for loop. use i is less then dvgAnnual.Columns.count instead of i is less than and equal to dvgAnnual.Columns.count. Just try it.

```
    for(int i = 0;i<dvgAnnual.Columns.count;i++)
    {
        dvgAnnual.Columns[i].HeaderText = str[i];  //<----- It's ok if it's stay in Loop For, event if I replace i by "0"
    }
```

Comment: so your syntax is incorrect in regards to the for loop it's lower case 
`for(int i = 0;i<dvgAnnual.Columns.count;i++)` if you are going to post an answer make sure it's proper syntax as well as it compiles correct your syntax error

Comment: I corrected my code. This is my failed when copy & pasted without checking it again. Sorry. The problem is the line dgvAnnual.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Col Name Here".

Comment: I pointed that out very quickly because I noticed someone downvoted you also the Header text should be a string and then inside the loop incrementing the column name as `"Col " + i.ToString()`  this could have been handled like this in the declaration of the str variable `string str = "Col ";`

Comment: I got an error at the first run (i=0). I have another way to fix it, but I want to ask you for clearly understanding it. tks

Answer (score -1):

Solution: the datagridview must be linked to a form

Example:
dgv_Example.Parent = frm_Example